# Unable to run FTPServer java file in tomcat server

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, tomcat6

My FTPserver is running in /folder/ftpserver.java in the newly deployed but before that means in the previous services deployed it was placed in /folder/folder1/folder2/ftpserver.

Even after changing the path and running the ftpserver in the new path, the tomcat6 server is taken the old and throwing the error which says

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: FTPServer (wrong name: Contact/share/sockclass/FTPServer)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: FTPServer. Program will exit.
```

how do i resolve this problem kindly help me I am novice for tomcat.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: FTPServer (wrong name: Contact/share/sockclass/FTPServer) From this exception , it seems that you have wrong class name which is inaccessible to tomact.

Comment: your class name is ftpserver not FTPServer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have mentioned your .java file name is ftpserver.java that means your class name must be

```
public class ftpserver{

}
```

So try invoking an object as

```
ftpserver ftps = new ftpserver();
```

good luck

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, due to the package it was creating an conflict now its working fine